# Getting template spelling without arguments, from a type, in libclang

Tags: python, c++, libclang

I can't find a way to get a "fully qualified name" for a template type without it's arguments, just plain name.

I.e. for a type which spells `NS::NS::TemplatedType<int, char>` just `NS::NS::TemplatedType`.

I know it's possible to do for a cursor in a field declaration; I just use:

`plain_type_name = "::".join([c.spelling for c in cursor.get_children()])`

Unfortunately in my case I don't have a cursor, because I've obtained type from a `TYPEDEF_DECL` cursor via `typedef_cursor.underlying_typedef_type`. So I guess I can just work with a type.

I am trying to process a typedef declaration like `typedef NS::NS::TemplatedType<int, char> TTic;` and I want to drop template arguments from the source type.

My target is python code but if I get a c++ solution I can work my way and translate it. Obviously I'd like to avoid regexping the spelling.

Comment: What would you expect to get for a type like A::B<int>::C<char>?

Comment: `A::B::C` just plain names, even for nested types. But currently I don't have such cases in my code base, so either solution to this problem is fine with me. I think it should be easy to adapt solution either way if I had one.